# how to manage code so that all database part of code been stored in module and front-end part is in main code

Tags: python, python-3.x

My whole code was too lengthy so I decided to make module that will execute all database part of code

1. So is it possible that while Executing my main code.
2. Module Gets Called.
3. Module Recognize the value that it is in Main code

Here is the main code:

```
from tkinter import *
from quesm import extfile


def register():
    w1 = Tk()
    w1.geometry('400x530')

    l3 = Label(w1, text='User Name').place(x=25, y=40)
    e3 = Entry(w1)
    e3.place(x=30, y=80 - 10)

    b2 = Button(w1, text='Register', command=extfile.detail_fetch)
                               # While Clicking Button "extfile.detail_fetch" gets Called


    b2.place(x=30, y=450)

    w1.mainloop()

register()
```

And here is the Module(extfile):

```
class extfile:
    def detail_fetch():
        uid = e3.get()          # OUTPUT: e3 NOT DEFINED
```

Comment: Where are you passing the parameters to the function? e3 is not a global variable that can be accessed anywhere; it has local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have initialized 'e3' in your main code. Therefore your module cannot find it. What you can do is make e3 an argument for your function, so when you call it, you pass e3 into it. Like:

```
class extfile:
    def detail_fetch(e3):
        uid = e3.get()
```

And then for your main code:

```
b2 = Button(w1, text='Register', command = lambda: extfile.detail_fetch(e3))
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying the OP's main code to pass e3 (the command argument assignment) and running it? You should get an error you cannot pass arguments to functions in Tkinter without using lambda functions

Comment: Ah yes, I will add that to my answer. Forgot about that part.